# magento2 Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be an object or a valid class name

Tags: magento2, php

guide me[![enter image description here][1]][1]

magento2 Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be an object or a valid class name
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkJfl.png